# ClassNotFoundException at Spring Bean Injection

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, classnotfoundexception

I have a Spring `beans.xml` that specifies a certain class `my.package.Class` to be injected somewhere in my code by **Autowiring**. The program is actually a web application inside a Tomcat container. Now when I launch Tomcat the logfile tells me `my.package.Class` cannot be found, even though its JAR is both in the classpath and the web application's lib/ directory. Do I have to tell Tomcat or Spring where to find the JAR, too, and if so: how?

Comment: is your .class file in folder WEB-INF/classes folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure, you have this code in your context:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="package.autowire.context" />
```

For more info you better read http://springindepth.com/book/in-depth-ioc-autowiring.html

By the way, check the default output folder in your project build path. That could also be the cause.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick!
I must say though that the Error description that Tomcat/Spring gave wasn't quite informative, don't you agree?